# Error: “Cannot implicitly convert type”

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on one project and I have a question regarding the converting type. I want to create simple search for my project, but it can't return result with this message :

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'EmployeeDataAccess.TimeWorkMonthly'

```
public TimeWorkMonthly Get(int id)
{
    using (EmployeeDbEntities Entities = new EmployeeDbEntities())
    {
        List<TimeWorkMonthly> persons = new List<TimeWorkMonthly>();
        var result = Entities.TimeWorkMonthlies
                             .Where(e => e.KartNo == id)
                             .Select(e => e)
                             .ToList();
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You return a list instead of a single object. Why do you have `List<TimeWorkMonthly> persons = new List<TimeWorkMonthly>();`? It doesn't do a thing. Why do you use `.Select(e => e)`? It doesn't do a thing. Why do you use `.ToList();` twice? The second time it doesn't doe a thing. One wonders if you wrote this code or copied it without understanding what it is supposed to do. Never use code you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your method is `TimeWorkMonthlies` but inside the method body  return `List<TimeWorkMonthlies>`

You should either

1. change your method return type to `IEnumerable<TimeWorkMonthlies>`
   (You could use `List<TimeWorkMonthlies>` but using an interface to abstract a collection type is better for many reasons)
2. Use `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault` or `Single` [extension methods of IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) if you aim to return only **one** element and you do not care about anything except for the first element

Which of those methods is better depends on your data and search criteria - i.e. **whether you expect this `ID` to be unique or not.**

From your semantics it looks like you're doing a sort of [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) like ID lookup, so my guess would be solution 2) and using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`

The last choice is how you want your program to behave if nothing is found by `ID`

1. If you want an exception, use `Single`
2. If you want a `null` use `SingleOrDefault`

In Summary, all you have to do is change your last line of code to

`return result.Single();`

(And ofcourse, you don't need a call to `ToList()` just before that)

Comment: I am a beginner and I did not understand the exact difference of these parameters. i want to see a lot of rows.your first solution was correct and works! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature indicates you just want to return a single object. But you're returning a List of objects. Using `.ToList()` is not appropriate when you just want to return one object. There are four appropriate extension methods:

[First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) - will return the first item from the collection and throw an exception if the collection is empty.

[FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) - will return the first item in the collection, or the default of the type if the collection is empty.

[Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) - if there is one item in the collection, it will return it. If there are no items in the collection an exception is thrown. If there are multiple items in the collection, an exception is thrown.

[SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) - if there is one item in the collection it will return it. If there are no items in the collection it will return the default value for the type. If there are multiple items in the collection it will thrown an exception.

Since you're searching by ID, you probably don't ever to expect to match two or more elements. So that rules out `First` and `FirstOrDefault`. You should use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` depending on what you want the behavior to be if there is no item found that has the matching ID.

```
public TimeWorkMonthly Get(int id)
{
    using (EmployeeDbEntities Entities = new EmployeeDbEntities())
    {
        var result = Entities.TimeWorkMonthlies.Where(e => e.KartNo == id).Single();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Note I eliminated the `persons` variable because you never did anything with it. And your usage of the `.Select` extension method was superflous since you just selected the same object already being iterated over. `Select` is for when you want to transform the object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your qry only . If you want to convert it with Tolist() function you have to change your qry

like this

```
public TimeWorkMonthly Get(int id)
{
    using (EmployeeDbEntities Entities = new EmployeeDbEntities())
        {

            var result = from x in Entities.TimeWorkMonthlies
                                 Where x.KartNo == id
                                 Select x;

            return result.ToList();
        }
}
```

You can now convert it to list by `tolist()` and use it according to your need.

Comment: And you can still not return a list if the signature promises a single object.

Comment: above example is able to convert a qry into list after this you can change return type of your function into list